# What does this hieroglyph mean? (appear in Gödel Escher, Bach book by Douglas R. Hofstadter)

Tags: reference-request

I found these  hieroglyphs:
[image]
at the end of the prologue of the book in Spanish, so I do not know if they appear in the original or another versions. It is on page XVII of this specific edition: https://www.amazon.com.mx/G%C3%83del-Escher-Bach-Douglas-Hofstadter/dp/8490660697

And my very natural question is... what they mean? and what "language" is this? Is original from the book or an old writing?  I tried to translate with Google image translator but it does not work.

Comment: It's the first few words of several (non-contiguous) verses of Genesis in Ancient Hebrew script, written together as though they formed a continuous text: In my early copy it was also printed upside down.

Comment: Yeah, it's the beginning of the Bible in Hebrew (בראשית ברא אלהים...), but in Paleo-Hebrew or Phoenecian script rather than the current square "Ashuri" script.

Comment: But it's not the beginning of the Bible: it's garbled. It contains those three words, immediately followed by וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֖ים יְהִי־א֑וֹר, the first three words of verse 3, then וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֖ים יְהִי־א֑וֹר, (verse 6) then וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים יִקָּו֨וּ הַמַּ֜יִם (verse 9), then וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים תַּדְשֵׁ֤א (verse 11). The discontinuities don't align with the line-breaks, so it looks as if somebody has miscopied some segments they didn't understand.

Answer (score 4):

It is the beginning of the Genesis in old Hebrew. It is explained at the end, in "Lista de ilustraciones" (list of ilustration) on page 835.

I think answer my own question is more useful than delete it.